# Generate 2^1000 combinations

Tags: python

I have task about knackpack problem. But for each subject in knackpack, we have two sets of weight-value parameters. For example:

1. Beer 1kg 15$, 2kg 20$
2. Water 5kg 30$, 10kg 40$

...etc

And we can choose only 1 set of weight-value parameter for each item.

So, what solution I see:

1. Generated all unique combinations of pair weigth-value from 2 array. In out we have 2<sup>n</sup> combinations.
2. For all combination we apply knackpack algorithm, then choose solution with max value - it's a best solution.

About problem - if we have about 10-15 items, it's normal. But we need solve this task for 1000 item, so it's 2<sup>1000</sup> unique combination.

Generate unique combine:

```
E=[[],[]]
weight1 = [1 2 3 4 5]
weight2 = [6 7 8 9 10]
for choices in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=len(off)):
E[0].append([(on[j] if choice else off[j]) for j, choice in enumerate(choices)])
value1 = [10 20 30 40 50]
value2 = [60 70 80 90 100]
for choices in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=len(off)):
E[1].append([(on[j] if choice else off[j]) for j, choice in enumerate(choices)])
```

If I do it for 30 item - my VDS go to down.

Please, suggest your solution to this problem.

Comment: 2^1000 is 10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376 so you won't want to generate all that many combinations, not even transiently.

Comment: You are using brute force, and `2^n` is a really bad complexity... You should try to make a better algorithm (one which already eliminates bad solutions), for that you have to use a paper, a pencil and logic. Also, you should see if your problem is parallelizeable.

Comment: You can't generate 2^1000 combinations. It would take you util the end of the universe, and several billion trillion universes after that. Knapsack Problems are a prime example where [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) should be used.

Comment: Bad luck, a NP-complete problem...

Comment: Just a funny side note to examplify the scale. ["The number of atoms in the entire observable universe is estimated to be within the range of 10^78 to 10^82."](http://www.universetoday.com/36302/atoms-in-the-universe/). And 10^300 < 2^1000. So even if you had a memory that would hold one state per atom ... yeah "several billion trillion universes" might be still a bit short.

Answer (score 3):

You want to resolve an NP-complete problem with brute force, and what's more with a high number of items. It will work theoretically, but you will need an eternity to do it. The problem you is not related to python, but to theoretical computer science.

The [Wikipedia page for the knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) contains several ideas about how to resolve it: you can use [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming), or even search for [approximations of the solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Approximation_algorithms).

The dynamic programming approach is based on tha fact that the problem have *optimal substructures*: it is possible to build the optimal solution for the n variables problem from the optimal solution of the n-1 variables problem.